# Pushing php foreach variable into the mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

My page1 has a simple form with name and list of items with checkbox. I'm passing the data into Page2 through post. When i echo the variable `$itemPush` it shows the exact list of items selected. But problem is when i'm adding the same variable into the sql query but it is not pushing the whole items into the table, instead it just pushes only the final item that was selected. Please help here's my code.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$items = $_POST['items'];

foreach($items as $selectedItems){
     $itemsPush =  'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
     echo $itemsPush;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (name, itemsPush) VALUES('$name', '$itemsPush')";
```

Comment: If `http://www.example.com` is always the same, why push it? also why not do `$itemsPush .= ` so that it appends into one long string? or is this not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the result before adding to DB else it will always add the last item.Do like below

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$items = $_POST['items'];
$itemsPush = '';
foreach($items as $selectedItems){
    $itemsPush .=  'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
    echo $itemsPush;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (name, itemsPush) VALUES('$name', '$itemsPush')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
foreach($items as $selectedItems){
     $itemsPush =  'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
     echo $itemsPush;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO pages (name, itemsPush) VALUES('$name', '$itemsPush')";
}
```

Comment: This won't do anything, there is no actual call to the SQL PDO

Comment: @nrathaus This is just an indicative code to point out that `$itemsPush` is being overwritten continuously and hence only the last value would be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined $itemsPush as an variable so for every loop it gets overwritten by latest value and hence only lasy value will be stored in it in the end of loop.

Either define $itemsPush as an array like

```
 $itemsPush[] = 'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
```

And then in the end encode the array as

```
$items = json_encode($itemsPush);
```

Then insert as below -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (name, itemsPush) VALUES('$name', '$items')";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$itemsPush` is just a variable. So when the loop ends it has the last value which was in the `$items` array. So if you want to have all the values of `$items` array den declare `$itemsPush` as array and keep storing the values in the loop.

```
 while($items as $selectedItems){
     $itemsPush[] = 'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
  }
```

Now you can use the `$itemsPush[]` the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$itemsPush = '';
foreach($items as $selectedItems){
    $itemsPush .=  'http://www.example.com/'.$selectedItems.',';
    echo $itemsPush;
}
 $itemsPush = serialize($itemsPush);
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (name, itemsPush) VALUES('$name', '$itemsPush')";
```